# Repeating sequences in an array

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

In this problem, I am to write a method that accepts an `ArrayList` of `strings` and an `integer`. In this case, the integer would repeat the individual word a number of times as indicated by the integer. For example, if the list stores the values `["how", "are", "you?"]` before the method is called and k is 4, it should store the values `["how", "how", "how", "how", "are", "are", "are", "are", "you?", "you?", "you?", "you?"]` If k is 0 or negative, the list should be empty after the call.

```
public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> thing, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) {
        thing.clear(); // if k is 0
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i< thing.size(); i+= k) {
        String temp = thing.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            thing.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue u r facing?

Comment: I got it to work, never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it please verify

```
 public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> thing, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) {
        thing.clear(); // if k is 0
        return;
    }

    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i< thing.size(); i++) {
        String temp = thing.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            newList.add(temp);
        }
    }
    thing.clear();
    thing.addAll(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it; just some rearranging and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solved it; just some rearranging and it worked.

```
public static void stutter(ArrayList<String> thing, int k) {
    if (k <= 0) {
        thing.clear();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< thing.size(); i+= k) {
        String temp = thing.get(i);
        for (int j = 1; j < k; j++) {
            thing.add(i, thing.get(i));
        }

        if (i == thing.size()) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If you guys can find any holes in this, feel free to point them out.

Comment: The time complexity of your solution will be greater than O(K*thing.size())